# Meaning of "頭に付く"?

Tags: meaning, idioms, phrases

I'm reading through a book about learning Mandarin written in Japanese. There's a section describing the basics of initials (声母【せいぼ】) and finals (韻母【いんぼ】) in Chinese syllables with the following sentence:

> 音節はまず大きく「声母」と「韻母」に分かれます。声母とは頭に付く子音のこと、韻母とはそれ以外の残りの部分で、ここに母音が含まれます。

There don't seem to be any entries for 頭に付く in any online dictionaries, or any alternate meanings of 頭 or 付く that would fit the context. Does anyone know what it means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

頭 usually refers to a physical `head`, and here it is used in an extended, more abstract, meaning, `front position`.

Compare with the use of the English `head` in a programming context: `C++ header files`. There's also the linguistic term `head-initial`.

Thus, 声母とは頭に付く子音 says that a 声母 is a 子音 placed at the the beginning of a 音節.

---

A few more examples:

- 単語の頭につく「S」の発音
- フォント名称の頭に「＠」が付くものが縦書きフォントになります。 「@extfont2.shx」
- 「『し』があたまにつくTVゲームと言えば？」「シュタインズゲート（XBOX360のADV）」
- 「妹須比智邇神（イモスヒチニノカミ）」： 原文の方の神名のあたまにつく「妹（イモ）」は、女性を意味する接頭語で、兄弟姉妹の妹に限らない。
- 第５問目：「”ド”があたまにつく、外国のなまえは？」「ドイツ」

---

From the 新和英大辞典:

> 〔最初〕 the beginning [start] 《of…》; the opening 《of…》; 〔上方〕 the top [head] 《of…》; 〔先端〕 the point [tip]《of…》.
>
> ･曲の頭　the opening [beginning, start] of a piece of music
>
> ･釘の頭　the head of a nail
>
> ･鼻の頭　the tip of one's nose
>
> ･月の頭　〔月初め〕 the beginning [start] of a month
>
> ･来月の頭にはゲラができてくる予定です.　The proofs are due to be ready at the beginning of next month.
>
> ･話の頭　the beginning [start, opening] of a conversation [discussion]